# Selenium driver navigates to url but in java it gives error or does not execute the next line

Tags: java, selenium

I just simply try to navigate to a url and when the code runs, the browser opens and the page that I want to work with gets loaded without a problem. However, the next line of code does not get executed and program just keep trying to navigate to url. And sometimes it gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to 
localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7307
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-CJSBFHF', ip: '10.0.0.65', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
at deneme.Deneme.main(Deneme.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7307
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:104)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:54)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:157)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:125)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
... 24 more
```

I have been using selenium for 2 years and I have never seen this problem.
My code is as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.yenicaggazetesi.com.tr/catida-noel-babayi-bekleyen-adam-yakalarsam-iman-et-diyecegim-2961v.htm");

System.out.println("Hello World!"); // this never gets executed and it just keeps running or gives the error
```

Comment: `Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7307`

Comment: Have you configured chromedriver.exe path as per latest chrome version you have.

Comment: I have tried a couple of other codes that I wrote this week. They work perfectly. I am not sure why this happens and why it gives error sometimes and other times just keep running. The other thing is, when I close the browser opened by the code,  It just keeps running at the back and my computer works like crazy.

Comment: are you doing chromedriver path setting like this `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\MyDocuments\\chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: @NarendraR Ofcourse. If I did not do that It would give a different error before this line. I have been using selenium library for 2 years.